# Use "n" in css styles (not just selectors)

Tags: html, css

I want to use the css below:

```
/* odd Elements */
.class:nth-of-type(2n+1){
    z-index: 1-n;
}

/* even Elements */
.class:nth-of-type(2n){
    z-index: 1+n;
}
```

The problem of course is that I can't access "n" from within an actually style, n is only available from the selector.

Is there any way I can determine which child I'm accessing using css alone? Or will I have to use JavaScript?

**Edit per comments request:**

The reason I want to do this is because I am making a library themed webpage that uses a book as it's main source of navigation.

As you scroll the page (swipe on mobile) the book's pages use css to flip to the next page.

However pages in a book stack on top of each other and so to make the flip look real the z index of the pages has to follow the css stacking order I requested above.

Here is a link of what I have so far showing what I want to accomplish:

http://amightywind.com/bookDemo/

Comment: In short: no, there isn't.

Comment: @connexo Alright thank you, off to JavaScript it  is

Comment: Also note that `.class:nth-of-type` will not select the `nth` element with that class. It will select the `nth` element of that *type*  if it also has that *class*.

Comment: you may probably show us your use case where you need it and explain the situation. Actually you think this is the way to do but probably you won't need all this and there is an easier way to do

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thank you for your suggestion, I edited my question to include what I'm trying to accomplish. If you have a better way of doing this please let me know.